# How can I access a variable from different file in kotlin?

Tags: android, variables, kotlin

I am trying to add items to a list and I want to display a list of all the items. I have made a list in `MainActivity.kt` but how can I access this list in another `kotlin` file?

Here I make the list and I add items.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    public val itemList= arrayListOf("one", "two", "three", "four")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        addItemBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val new = addItemTxt.text.toString()
            if (!itemList.contains(new)){
                itemList.add(new)
            }
            addItemTxt.text.clear()
        }


        listButton.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, ListChoose::class.java))
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: hi OP :) check out my answer, maybe it teaches you something or helps you out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for access only variable.

Make it's access specifier public.

```
public val itemList= arrayListOf("one", "two", "three", "four")
```

Then :

```
var itemList = MainActivity().itemList
```

Pass your List with intent to Next Activity where you can remove or edit items from it.

```
listButton.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this, NextActivity::class.java)
    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("itemList", itemList)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Get Data from That activity :

```
var itemList = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("itemList")
```

Comment: If I add something it always goes back to only four items. It add it at first but then it disappears.I try to do the same in the other way but it crashes

Comment: if it works for you accept it as answer. Below downvote click on the right sign